# GNU find -exec command {} ; vs -exec command {} +

Tags: linux, syntax, gnu

Can anyone please explain the difference between the following two GNU **find** options for the **-exec** argument:

1. find -exec *command* {} **;**
2. find -exec *command* {} **+**

The man page does a good example of explaining that "one might prefer the **-exec ... +** or better the **-execdir ... +** syntax for performance and security reasons" but I can't seem to wrap my head around the basic premise of **;** vs **+**

Any help is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: They are described under `-exec command ;` and `-exec command +` sections.

Answer (score 4):

The `;` syntax executes the command for each single match. The `+` command runs the command with a long list of matches as arguments to the command.

For example:

```
$ find
.
./a.txt
./b.png

$ find . -exec echo {} \;
.
./a.txt
./b.png

$ find . -exec echo {} +
. ./a.txt ./b.png
```

Comment: Thanks very much choroba for the clear explanation and example! I finally understand!  :)